# Binomial Co-efficients as a basis for Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions

Well, I was just doing some random reading, and came across this:

Let $P(n)$ be a polynomial of degree $d$, further, define, $p_k = \Delta^k(P(n))|_{n=0}$.
(Here, $\Delta$ indicates the forward difference operator.)

Then, $P(n)= \displaystyle\sum^d_{i=0} p_i \binom{n}{i}$, where, $\binom {n}{i}$ is the generalised binomial co-efficient.

This seems like a pretty marvellous result, and I notice the similarity to Maclaurin or Taylor series expansions, but, well, does anybody know where I can find a proof? And where could I read more about results like this?

Comment: The keyword here is "calculus of finite differences." The proof is by induction on the degree.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the heads up. It's curiously fortuitous that you, of all people, commented. I was, after all, reading your notes at the time.

As for the induction, well, I feel sheepish that I didn't try it beforehand. Regardless, I tried it myself, but it seems incredibly messy. Would you mind handing me some direction, man?

Answer (score 1):

Apply the operators $\Delta^k|_{n=0}$ on both sides for all $k=0,1,...$ and check you get the same every time.

The operators applied on the binomial coefficients act nicely. Use the basic property of the binomial coefficients.

Of course, you also need to prove that if a polynomial gives you zero after applying all these operators then you get zero. But this clearly gives you that the polynomial is constant at too many points.

Comment: Ha, I tried that, and yes they do act rather prettily, indeed.
I was wondering though if it were possible to derive this sort of formula analytically? Otherwise, it just seems sort of marvellously contrived, I suppose.

Comment: What would it be analytically? For example: How would it be a proof of $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{d}P^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k$ analytically? Here we are proving the same type of formula but for finite differences instead of derivatives. It is likely that any proof of one can also be adapted to the other.